# Excel Macro to update Cells automatically based on User selection

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a Macro that updates 4 Cell if the User select "Mailing" From Cell A1. If the User selects "Mailing" in A1, then Automatically update A2,A3,A4, and A5 to Value in B1. If the User selects something other than "Mailing", Then all four cells should be blank and the user should be able to type in any value. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

I have gotten this far, but VBA is not my thing:

```
Sub test()
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$A$1" And Target.Value = "Mailing" Then
        Range("A2:A4").Value = "B1"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: worksheet_change is its own sub located in the worksheet code.  You cannot put a sub inside another sub.  Remove the `Sub Test()` and make sure the code is on the correct code sheet.

Comment: Thanks, Scott! For some reason when I try to run without the Sub Test() it doesn't run and it asks me to create a Macro. Thanks

Comment: You run it by changing a Cell in that Worksheet. You may have an issue if Target is more than 1 cell - like select a block of cells and press delete.

Comment: John, have you put your code in the worksheet and not in a separate module?

Comment: delete `Sub test()` and copy the rest of the code, then right click on the tab / sheet that you want this code to act, choose `view code` and paste it there. Now, when the value of cell A1 is Mailing it will work

Comment: @Ibo: That is what I did but when I run it says Run-time error 13; Type Mismatch

Comment: I will answer it in the answer section, please accept it as the answer and upvote it if it worked for you. It is working on my side

Answer (score 0):

As the others have mentioned, you just need to put it to `Sub Worksheet_Change`. Note that if you are "typing" the word into cell A1, you will actually be in A2 after the "Enter".

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Range("A1").Value = "Mailing" Then
        Range("A2:A4").Value = "B1"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to change the value of some of the cells in your code, so the code should run itself. You need to turn off events before changing the cell values and then turn it back on:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$A$1" And Target.Value = "Mailing" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range("A2:A4").Value = "B1"
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```